# How do you convert formatted 'epi-week' to date using Python?

Tags: python, date, week-number

I am currently trying to learn how to apply Data Science skills which I am learning through Coursera and Dataquest to little personal projects.

I found a dataset on Google BigQuery from the US Department of Health and Human Services which includes all weekly surveillance reports of nationally notifiable diseases for all U.S. cities and states published between 1888 and 2013.

I exported the data to a .csv file and imported it into a Jupyter notebook which I am running through Anaconda. Upon looking at the header of the dataset I noticed that the dates/weeks are shown as 'epi_week'.

I am trying to make the data more readable and useable for some analysis, to do this I was hoping to conver it into something along the lines of DD/MM/YYYY or Week/Month/Year etc.

I did some research, apparently epi-weeks are also referred to as CDC weeks and so far I found an extension/package for python 3 which is called "epiweeks".

Using the epiweeks package I can turn some 'normal' dates into what the package creator refers to into some sort of an epi weeks form but they look nothing like what I can see in the dataset.

---

For example if I use todays date, the 24th of May 2019 (24/05/2019) then the output is: "Week 21 of Year 2019" but this is what the first four entrys in the data (and following the same format, all the other ones) look like:

epi_week

'197006'

'197007'

'197008'

'197012'

---

```py
In [1]: disease_header

Out [1]: 
[['epi_week', 'state', 'loc', 'loc_type', 'disease', 'cases', 'incidence_per_100000']]

In [2]: disease[:4]

Out [2]:
[['197006', 'AK', 'ALASKA', 'STATE', 'MUMPS', '0', '0'],
['197007', 'AK', 'ALASKA', 'STATE', 'MUMPS', '0', '0'],
['197008', 'AK', 'ALASKA', 'STATE', 'MUMPS', '0', '0'],
['197012', 'AK', 'ALASKA', 'STATE', 'MUMPS', '0', '0']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The [epiweeks](https://pypi.org/project/epiweeks/) package was developed to solve problems like the one you have here.

With the example data you provided, let's create a new column with week ending date:

```py
import pandas as pd
from epiweeks import Week

columns = ['epi_week', 'state', 'loc', 'loc_type',
           'disease', 'cases', 'incidence_per_100000']
data = [
    ['197006', 'AK', 'ALASKA', 'STATE', 'MUMPS', '0', '0'],
    ['197007', 'AK', 'ALASKA', 'STATE', 'MUMPS', '0', '0'],
    ['197008', 'AK', 'ALASKA', 'STATE', 'MUMPS', '0', '0'],
    ['197012', 'AK', 'ALASKA', 'STATE', 'MUMPS', '0', '0']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

# Now create a new column with week ending date in ISO format
df['week_ending'] = df['epi_week'].apply(lambda x: Week.fromstring(x).enddate())
```

That results in something like:

[image]

I recommend you to have a look over the epiweeks package [documentation](https://epiweeks.readthedocs.io/) for more examples.

If you only need to have year and week columns, that can be done without using the epiweeks package:

```
df['year'] = df['epi_week'].apply(lambda x: int(x[:4]))
df['week'] = df['epi_week'].apply(lambda x: int(x[4:6]))
```

That results in something like:

[image]